# Derivations of algebra of smooth $g$-valued function?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebras

Let $M$ is a smooth n-manifold and $g$ is a $Z_2$-graded Lie algebra, we denote the algebra of smooth $g$-valued function on $M$ by $C^{\infty} (M,g)$. I wanna find all graded derivation of $C^{\infty} (M,g)$ and their relation to algebra of smooth function and smooth vector field on $M$. In the case of space-time manifold and special lie algebra this obtained some wonderful result. 
let me know Any reference related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is finite-dimensional, the algeba in question is isomorphic to $g \otimes C^\infty(M,\mathbb R)$. There is a full description of derivations of Lie algebras of the form $L \otimes A$ in terms of $L$ and $A$ (see, for example, arXiv:math/0302334, Corollary 2.2 and references therein). For example, if $L$ is perfect, centerless and central, then $Der(L\otimes A) \simeq (Der(L) \otimes A) \oplus Der(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

To describe $C^{\infty}(M,\mathfrak{g})$ as an algebra, choose a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$. This yields a vector space isomorphism $\mathfrak{g}\cong\mathbb{R}^n$, $n=\dim_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathfrak{g})$. This gives algebra isomorphisms $$C^{\infty}(M,\mathfrak{g})\cong C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R}^n)\cong C^{\infty}(M)^{\oplus n}.$$ In terms of ordinary algebra derivations, we have $$Der(C^{\infty}(M,\mathfrak{g}))\cong Der(C^{\infty}(M))^{\oplus n}.$$

I am not entirely sure what relevant structures the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading gives us on the level of $C^{\infty}(M,\mathfrak{g})$ and its derivations. Here is one possibility. The grading on $\mathfrak{g}$ gives a vector space decomposition $\mathfrak{g}=V\oplus W$, where $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of $\mathfrak{g}$. Hence, $C^{\infty}(M,\mathfrak{g})$ is naturally isomorphic to $C^{\infty}(M,V)\oplus C^{\infty}(M,W)$. So, the derivations naturally decompose into a direct sum. We can then apply the above argument to describe derivations of $C^{\infty}(M,V)$ and $C^{\infty}(M,W)$, respectively. I am not sure if this is the sort of thing you are seeking.